# Can I use JDK7 with cloudbees builds

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

Can I choose a JDK I need on a job by job basis on my Cloudbees Jenkins builds (DEV@cloud)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - in the JDK dropdown you can choose the one you want. It is noted here http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Jenkins+Build+Machine+Specifications